# Invalid token errors with enums

Tags: c#

I'm having a little trouble with this code that I'm writing for a simple program. I get tons of errors saying "invalid token".

The program basically asks for 2 integers and sums them up, but the program needs to be called in another method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AustinPDangeloJPA03
{
    class Add
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double num1,
                   num2,
                   sum;

            Console.Write("Enter the First integer: ");
            num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //First Integer entered and storred 
            Console.Write("Enter the Second integer: ");
            num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Second Integer entered and storred
            sum = Display(double a, double b);
            //First and second numbers added together

            Console.WriteLine(" {0} + {1} = {2} ",num1,num2,sum); 
            //displays the sum

            //Instructs the user to press the Enter key to end the program
            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to terminate the program...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            }//Closes Main Method

        static enum Display(a,b)
        {
            double c = a + b;
            return c;
        }//closes display method

    }//Closes Class Add
}
```

Comment: What do you believe "static enum" means? Whatever you think it means, that's not what it means. Can you explain what you think this does? I am very interested in learning about how people's intuitions about what code means lead them astray, so that we can design languages that do not lead users into these pitfalls. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: Very well said.  To answer your question, I suspect that he thinks `enum` is a numeric type, or that he picked a keyword at random.

Comment: "I get tons of errors saying "invalid token"" -- Show us at least a couple of the errors, and which line numbers they refer to.

Telling us there is an "invalid token" *somewhere* in your code is abusive of the same people you are asking for help from!

Comment: I know its homework and you've probably asked to comment your code in a very particular way -- but really, if I saw comments like `Console.WriteLine(...); // writes to the console`, `i++; // increments 'i' variable`, or `// closes main method` I'd stab the original author in the eye. Comments after every line of code, particularly self-explanatory lines, are simply noise. Please malign your instructor on my behalf.

Answer (score 4):

This is not correct:

```
static enum Display(a,b)
{
    double c = a + b;
    return c;

 }
```

The [enum keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28VS.80%29.aspx) is used to declare an enumeration.  In order to define a method, you need a valid return type (such as `int` or `double`), and you need to provide the proper types for the individual arguments.  You can optionally add `static` if you want it to be a static method, but that depends on its purpose.

I suspect you want to use something more like:

```
 double Add(double a, double b)
 {
     // ...
```

If you then correct the line that called this method:

```
 sum = Display(double a, double b);
```

This should compile and give you what you expect.

Comment: @Slaks: Wasn't trying to provide a full solution - just enough hints, and reasoning why, to get the OP there...

Comment: To elaborate on @ReedCopsey about enum. From the docs you can read that: The default underlying type of the enumeration elements is int. This means enums basically is int.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Display` method is not declared correctly.

You need to declare a method that takes two numbers and returns a third number.
Consult your textbook and assignment for more information on how to declare a method and which types to use.

You're also not calling it correctly; method calls do not take types.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not the source of your errors, it does indicate a misunderstanding of types:

```
double num1, num2,sum;
[...]
num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

The first line declares some `double` variables.
The second line tries to parse `int` variables.

While the `int` will get auto-converted to a `double`, your code will be better if it is consistent with the use of types.  You should switch to either `int` types, or to `Double.Parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `enum` keyword is for creating enumerations, for example:

```
public enum Color { Red, Green, Blue };
```

You have to specify a data type as return type for your `Display` method, and data types for the parameters:

```
static double Display(double a, double b) {
  double c = a + b;
  return c;
}
```

Also, you don't specify data types when you call the method, so change that to:

```
sum = Display(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to:

```
    double sum = Display(num1, num2);
```

And change your Display method to be a method.

```
    private static double Display(double a, double b)
    {
        double c = a + b;
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: ditto what Reed said. As this is a QA site.